# How to determine cause of VS2013 error in editor extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I attach the debugger to a web page, as soon as a the first breakpoint is hit I get an error dialog saying "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.".

In ActivityLog.xml I find this:

```
type: Error
source: Editor or Editor Extension
description: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: sp&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider..ctor(IServiceProvider sp, Boolean defaultServices)&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Implementation.ContainedLanguage.ContainedLanguageHostAdapter.Microsoft.Web.Editor.ContainedLanguage.IContainedLanguageHost.get_BufferGraph()&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.SyntaxCheck.CssErrorTag..ctor(ITextBuffer textBuffer, ICssError error)&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.SyntaxCheck.CssErrorTagger.CollectTags(SnapshotSpan span, CssErrorList errors, SortedRangeList`1 tagSpans)&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.SyntaxCheck.CssErrorTagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTagsForBuffer&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
```

None of which points to anything I am familiar with.

Comment: Attach a debugger and find out.

Comment: Disable the Web Essentials extension.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this... The Web Essentials extension is not the cause -- I get the same error and I don't have that extension. Attaching a debugger won't help because the error is thrown by Visual Studio itself, not the code in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

Apparently inline images don't paste...
in tools>options>editor>all languages>scroll bars
turned off "show annotations".